# Non-constant expression specified where only constant expressions are allowed

Tags: verilog, system, system-verilog

I have my dummy code in here.
I remember coding like this before.
But I'm getting an error saying non-constant expression is used where only constant expressions are allowed.
If I have to do the same, how else can I do it without this error ?

```
typedef struct packed {
    logic row;
    logic col;
} Table;

Table [9:0]table;
logic a;
assign a = input & Valid;
generate
  genvar i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) begin
     if (table[i] == a) begin
        assign count = 0;
     end
  end
endgenerate

Error Message:
Non-constant expression (a) specified where only constant expressions are allowed
```

Comment: most likely you are compiling it in a **non**-*system*-verilog mode.

Comment: I'm running lint.

Comment: Is it because I'm trying to compare logic? I know this kind of comparison would work with parameters. Does it work with logic too?

Comment: I'm going to close this ticket. The issue here is we cant use signals inside generate loop. Generate loops only take static values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with conditional generate  `if (table[i] == a)`. Both `table[i]` and `a` are variables, not constants. Most likely you want to change this to procedural `if code in an` always` block

Comment: Thanks Dave. The issue was that I have kept everything in the generate loop.

Comment: @user3309525, don't understand if your comment is another question. Do you understand what is needed to fix it?

Comment: Yup. I was able to fix the issue.